# Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication in c# application

Tags: c#

I have c# application that run on a client machine and have access to remote PC database, but when i run the program it displays

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication" error.

I try all the things. I try this:

> Data Source=Elias;Initial Catalog=FIDs; user id=sa; Password=serverpassword;Integrated Security=true;`

And this:

> Data Source=192.168.42.2, 1433;Initial Catalog=FIDs; user id=sa; Password=gezahegnelias@gmail.com;Integrated Security=true;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove `Integrated Security=true;` from the connection string. This is telling your application to use your Windows credentials instead of the username and password you are supplying.